# How to clear the selected point color of UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, ios4

I am creating an app that has drawing module and what i am try to do that i have a image and i have to draw text on it.Now i need to remove the text by eraser and draw pad(UIImageView) height must be infinite.So i need to scroll the image View as well as apply drawing on it also.If anyone have any answer then please reply

Comment: Your question is a little confusing, can you clarify it please?

Comment: Sorry for that...I have a ImageView(320*416) for show background and above this view i have another ImageView(320*416) on which i draw some text in black color.I want to earse this color by my touch on screen.(means whenever i will touch..Only that point color should erase.).I use the logic that i will pick the background imageview pixel color and paint it on above drawing imageview but It is not working properly.I use this link for that..http://www.markj.net/iphone-uiimage-pixel-color/..

Answer (score 0):

I had answered a question like this before .... Maybe this would help you :) Also you would see a long discussion which I think would be helpful ....

[Writing on ImageView in Iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11828200/can-we-write-by-dragging-finger-over-screen/11828810#11828810)